# AEM 6.3 upgrade issue "Error exists in the bytecode"

Tags: java, aem, powermock

Build issues after AEM 6.3 upgrade.
Tried both uber-jar 6.3.0 api and obfuscated-apis as dependency

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.home.components.AppTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.841 
sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.home.components.AppTest
com.home.components.AppTest  Time elapsed: 0.271 sec  <<< 
ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before 
return
Exception Details:
Location:
com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUsePojo.<init>()V @1: return
Reason:
Error exists in the bytecode
Bytecode:
0x0000000: 2ab1                                   

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer$ParameterizedConstructorInstantiator.biggestConstructor(FieldInitializer.java:265)
at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer$ParameterizedConstructorInstantiator.instantiate(FieldInitializer.java:235)
at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.acquireFieldInstance(FieldInitializer.java:123)
at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.initialize(FieldInitializer.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.ConstructorInjection.processInjection(ConstructorInjection.java:52)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.relayProcessToNextStrategy(MockInjectionStrategy.java:89)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:71)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjection$OngoingMockInjection.apply(MockInjection.java:92)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultInjectionEngine.injectMocksOnFields(DefaultInjectionEngine.java:20)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:100)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:35)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:60)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug with java jdk 1.7 and powermock. Check [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/525) post for more details on the bug.

Powermock / Javassist creates illegal constructors for JDK 1.7.0u65 and 1.8.0u11 with -target 7 #525

Try upgrading your jdk version to `7u75` or `8u51` or higher as stated in the post and rebuild your project using the new version. This should resolve your issue.

Not recommended - If you cannot go to newer versions of java due to project constraints use the `-noverify` param to initialize jvm.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I will check on JDK version but this was working fine till I updated the AEM related uber jar from 6.2 to 6.3.